# How to format string in XML element using xslt

Tags: html, xml, xslt, soa, osb

I have an XML in which one of the element has list of comments concatenated. I need to format that and map it to a target xml node.

Input XML element value:

```
<Comment> TJ-TACO JOHNS Dented Cans - RFS# D2804 and D01441)Inspect entire load for dented cans.2)Pay close attention to hidden damage of dentedcans, specially towards the bottom cornersof pallet.3)If dented cans found,take pictures, rejectimplicated product & document in COMMENTS on PO.4)Report issue to buyer to notify vendor.5)Report issue to FSQA to notify Taco Johns QA. </Comment>
```

Expected Output format:

```
<Output>
TJ-TACO JOHNS Dented Cans - RFS# D2804 and D0144
1)Inspect entire load for dented cans.
2)Pay close attention to hidden damage of dentedcans, specially towards the bottom cornersof pallet.
3)If dented cans found,take pictures, reject implicated product & document in COMMENTS on PO.
4)Report issue to buyer to notify vendor.
5)Report issue to FSQA to notify Taco Johns QA.
</Output>
```

How do I achieve this in xslt?

Comment: You write XSLT rather than ask someone else to do it for you.  This is a Q/A site, not a code-on-demand site.

Comment: The XML value cannot be reformatted because there is no way for the computer to know that `D01441` and `D0144 1` differ. You could look for a number followed by `)`, but how many numbers appear in the list? Any solution will be brittle at best. Change the input document format to capture the list items using XML elements. Then use XSLT to format the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <xsl:template match="Comment">
    <Output>
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="[0-9]\)">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(0)"></xsl:value-of>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </Output>
</xsl:template>
```

you can check script at http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/nbUY4ko

*But there is no extra information in your question, so this is worked only for **single digit number**.*